# document.getElementById("id") works, but $("#id") does not jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am iterating over some elements and I have found that `document.getElementById("id")` works, but `$("#id")` does not.  Why?

Edit: I suppose it wouldn't hurt to post code?

```
function myFunction() {
    var token, tokens, id, input;
    $("[id^=\"some_id_\"]").each(function() {
        tokens = this.id.split("_");
        id = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
        input = document.getElementById("some_form_element_" + id);  //WORKS
        //input = $("#some_form_element_" + id); //DOESNT, alerts undefined

        alert(input.value);
    });
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like? Have you included jQuery? Get any JS-errors?

Comment: What happens? what is the error displayed?

Comment: maybe you have multiple elements with the same id

Comment: Did you properly escape the ID in the selector case?

Comment: Do you use another javascript libraries?

Comment: What does `typeof jQuery` return?

Comment: is the element you are trying to call already in you DOM? is this called in the window.load or the document.ready function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are alerting `input.value`, `value` is not defined on the jQuery wrapper object.

`document.getElementById` will directly return a DOM element. But `$()` returns a jQuery object that wraps the DOM element. You can get at the input's value in the jQuery case with `$('#someId').attr('value');` or `$('#someId').val()`

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates: http://jsfiddle.net/CK2xr/

Answer (score 2):

It's probably the case that you're:

1. Testing in IE and
2. Using a "name" attribute instead of "id".

Internet Explorer (at least, the older versions) return elements when the "name" attribute matches the "id" you're looking for, in one of the more absurd API idiocies those browsers perpetuate.

*edit* — to clarify: Internet Explorer's `document.getElementById()` function will match on the "id" attribute *or* the "name" attribute, and it returns the first one it finds in the DOM. The jQuery API tries to actually satisfy the semantics of the "#" selector syntax, which — even in IE — only matches "id" attributes.

Comment: Jquery works perfectly in IE, would you give a case when the id selector would fail in IE

Comment: I did not say that **jQuery** worked incorrectly, I said that IE's `document.getElementById()` is broken.

Comment: That's wierd, you would think that IE wouldn't have such a problem. /sarcasm